# How to start a mongodb shell in docker container?

Tags: mongodb, docker

To start the container, I am typing the following command:

```
sudo docker run -i -t -p 28000:27017 mongo:latest /usr/bin/mongod --smallfiles
```

But I want to open the shell in this container to type the mongo commands.
What command should I run to do the same?

Answer (score 239, accepted):

You can run the interactive mongo shell by running the following command:

```
docker run -it -p 28000:27017 --name mongoContainer mongo:latest mongosh
```

Otherwise, if your container is already running, you can use the `exec` command:

```
docker exec -it mongoContainer mongosh
```

Comment: Error: Command not found: exec
Error: Command not found: -it
Usage: docker [OPTIONS] COMMAND [arg...]
 -H=[unix:///var/run/docker.sock]: tcp://host:port to bind/connect to or unix://path/to/socket to use

Comment: What version of docker do you currently have installed? The exec command has been introduced in version 1.3.0

Comment: you need to upgrade, we're up to 1.8 and there's been a lot of changes to the plumbing of docker. that or use nsentry (not sure if it support your version of docker).

Comment: As booyaa mentioned, you should update docker on your host as you are currently using an old version that does not offer the latest available features

Comment: I updated the docker version and it helped. Thanks a lot!

Comment: mongo no longer works, use mongosh instead.

Comment: As @Herii said `docker exec -it mongoContainer mongo` results in `bash: mongo: command not found`. Please update your answer to use `mongosh`

Comment: in Windows 11 and Docker desktop version 4.17, this command worked for me:
"docker exec -it "YourContainerName" mongo"

Answer (score 27):

The thing that I struggled too but found a solution:

```
docker pull mongo
docker run --name CONTAINERNAME --restart=always -d -p 8080:8080 mongo mongod --auth
sudo docker exec -i -t CONTAINERNAME bash
mongo
use admin
db.createUser({user:"user", pwd:"password", roles:[{role:"root", db:"admin"}]})
exit && exit
```

Now you have created a running Docker container with everything you need. Now if you want to connect from any client with an admin user, just run this

```
mongo -u "user" -p "password" HOSTIP --authenticationDatabase "admin"
```

Comment: As a security precaution, use the `-p` flag, but don't enter your password as it will be present in your bash  / shell history.

Answer (score 18):

Download the latest MongoDB Docker image from Docker Hub

```
sudo docker pull mongo
```

Now set up MongoDB container

```
docker run --name containername mongo
```

Interact with the database through the bash shell client

```
docker exec -it containername bash
```

Launch the MongoDB shell client

```
mongosh #now it is mongosh to access shell
```

Answer (score 13):

Extending and updating `@vladzam` answer and if your container is already running in `docker`, you can use the exec `mongosh` command with login and pass options like this:

```
docker exec -it database-dev mongosh -u "myLogin" -p "myPass"
```

Answer (score 6):

It depends which version of MongoDB you're running.

Please see the differences here : [The MongoDB Shell versus the Legacy mongo Shell](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/#the-mdb-shell-versus-the-legacy-mongo-shell).

For example, with **Mongo 3** the executable was `mongo` :

```
$ docker run --rm mongo:3 which mongo mongosh mongod
/usr/bin/mongo
/usr/bin/mongod
```

With **Mongo 5** both `mongo` and `mongosh` are present :

```
$ docker run --rm mongo:5 which mongo mongosh mongod
/usr/bin/mongo
/usr/bin/mongosh
/usr/bin/mongod
```

With **Mongo 6** you can only use the newest `mongosh` :

```
$ docker run --rm mongo:6 which mongo mongosh mongod
/usr/bin/mongosh
/usr/bin/mongod
```

Now if you want to try it, run a MongoDB instance :

```
$ docker run -d -p 29000:27017 --name mongodb-6 mongo:6
```

Then connect a shell :

```
$ docker exec -it mongodb-6 mongosh
```

You'll get something like :

```
Current Mongosh Log ID: 632456e42dbc88aa0bfe612f
Connecting to:          mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.5.4
Using MongoDB:          6.0.1
Using Mongosh:          1.5.4
...
```

You can also pass options like :

```
$ docker exec -it mongodb-6 mongosh --version
```

Answer (score 5):

```
docker exec -it mongoContainer mongosh
```

i tried mongo, mongod, and mongodb but failed. Then i changed it to mongosh and it works!