# Clear all entries in Docker mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, docker

Is there an easy way to clear a mongodb database running in docker?

Or possibly delete it all and create it again?

Comment: Can't you just remove the container and recreate another one?

Comment: For reference, `docker container ls --all` then `docker container rm <id>`, then build again

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of ways:

- The same way you would normally clear a mongodb database. You're running it in Docker, but it is a real mongodb after all. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366397/delete-everything-in-a-mongodb-database), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944729/how-to-start-a-mongodb-shell-in-docker-container).
- If you've mounted your database's data as a volume on the host system using -v on the *docker run* command, you can just clear this folder out.
- If you haven't, the data lives in the container. You can remove the container and recreate it (docker rm container_name). *Or* run a shell in the container and remove the data from the container's filesystem (docker exec -it container_name bash).

Regarding the last option, you shouldn't be in this scenario because your data *should* live on the host system and your container *should* be disposable.

Comment: You can also delete volumes using _docker volume rm <volume_name>_

Answer (score 4):

```
docker exec -it mongodb_container bash -c "mongo db-name --eval 'db.dropDatabase()'"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a case with slightly different requirements:

- `docker-compose`
- authentication needed
- bash *variable expansion* (the container was running with environemt variables `MONGO_USER` & `MONGO_PASSWORD` already set)

So, for anyone who might need a handy one-liner to authenticate and drop a mongo db with `docker`, here it is :

```
docker-compose exec mongo_container_name /bin/bash -c 'mongo database_name -u $MONGO_USER -p $MONGO_PASSWORD --authenticationDatabase admin --eval "db.dropDatabase();"'
```

---

And if you add a `Makefile` to the "mix", it's exactly the same but it needs `$$` to the variables:

```
db-reset:
    docker-compose exec mongo_container_name /bin/bash -c 'mongo database_name -u $$MONGO_USER -p $$MONGO_PASSWORD --authenticationDatabase admin --eval "db.dropDatabase();"'
```