# Unable to access mongodb running in a docker from local machine

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am trying to access the mongodb running in a docker from my local machine however I am seeing this error message:

Error: couldnt connect to server localhost:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to localhost:27017 (127.0.0.1:27017) :: caused by :: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

commands tried to used to access mongo on my local machine:

`mongo localhost:27017`

`mongo 172.17.0.2:27017`(container's ip)

command used to run mongodb on docker
`docker run -d -p 27017:27017 mongo:latest`

Please advice. Thank you.

Comment: Is your `docker ps -a` show that your container is working

Comment: yes it is up, running.

Comment: Can you also try to connect it with `Robo 3T` or `MongoDB Compass`

Comment: the port 27017 is open? lsof -i:27017 to check

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32944935/3500157

Comment: @YuTing i could access from Robo 3T but using the Host's ip address.